# What is the best way to kill a angular service worker and replace with another one?

Tags: angular, service-worker

Seeing i have a app in production using the @angular/service-worker, if by anyway he get bugged and i want to force a clear and replace with another, what is the best way to do it?

I already saw the https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-devops#service-worker-safety topic. But it not explain how to safely replace a sw with another one.
Maybe renaming the `ngsw.json` and registering the `ngsw-worker.js` with another name?

Like: 

`ServiceWorkerModule.register('/another-ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })`

???

Ps: I want to keep making cache and everything that it makes a pwa, but want to save the clients from seen a old version with the bugged sw that don't update.

Comment: did you find any solution